# Laravel 5.7 email verification expiration time

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.7

I would like to customize the time users have to verify their email address that happens through the built in Auth (since 5.7).

In `config/auth` there is:

```
'passwords' => [
        'users' => [
            'provider' => 'users',
            'table' => 'password_resets',
            'expire' => 60,
        ],
    ],
```

But I haven't found anything similar for email verification. There is also no mention in [the official documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/verification).

Comment: I doubt there is such an option.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In deed the options is not there in Laravel, but since laravel makes use of the following:

- a trait `MustVerifyEmail` (in `Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User` class extended by the main `User` model)
- Event and Notification

In the `MustVerifyEmail` trait, there's a method called `sendEmailVerificationNotification`. This is where the Notification `VerifyEmail` class referenced by [@nakov's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53636509/5704410) and its function `verificationUrl` is used:

```
/**
 * Send the email verification notification.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function sendEmailVerificationNotification()
{
    $this->notify(new Notifications\VerifyEmail);
}
```

Since we know this, we can do the following:

- Extend the `Notifications\VerifyEmail` to our custom `VerifyEmail` class
- override the implementation of `verificationUrl`
- override the implementation of the `sendEmailVerificationNotification` method in the `User` model to use our new `VerifyEmail` class.

Having done the above, our `User` model will have the following method:

```
/**
 * Send the email verification notification.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function sendEmailVerificationNotification()
{
    $this->notify(new \App\Services\Verification\VerifyEmail);
}
```

Now we make use of our custom `VerifyEmail` class. Then our new `VerifyEmail` class would look like this:

```
namespace App\Services\Verification;

use Illuminate\Support\Carbon;
use \Illuminate\Support\Facades\URL;

class VerifyEmail extends \Illuminate\Auth\Notifications\VerifyEmail
{
    protected function verificationUrl($notifiable)
    {
        return URL::temporarySignedRoute(
            'verification.verify', Carbon::now()->addMinute(3), ['id' => $notifiable->getKey()]
        );  //we use 3 minutes expiry
    }
}
```

Well, apart from the explanations, the process is quite straight forward. I hope it is easy to grasp. Cheers!

Answer (score 18):

Whilst the question specifically addresses Laravel 5.7, I feel that it is worth mentioning that as of Laravel 5.8, it is possible to achieve this with a config variable. My search for customising the verification expiration time returned this question as the top result, hence my addition.

If we check out `Illuminate\Auth\Notifications\VerifyEmail`, the `verificationUrl` method now looks like this:

```
protected function verificationUrl($notifiable)
{
    return URL::temporarySignedRoute(
        'verification.verify',
        Carbon::now()->addMinutes(Config::get('auth.verification.expire', 60)),
        ['id' => $notifiable->getKey()]
    );
}
```

As such, we can just add this block to `config/auth.php` to customise the time without needing to extend the classes or anything:

```
'verification' => [
    'expire' => 525600, // One year - enter as many mintues as you would like here
],
```

**UPDATE**: I've written about the above approach, as well as another on customising the process by overiding the `verificationUrl` method to give you more flexibility, [on my blog](https://bannister.me/blog/customise-email-verification-expiration/).

Answer (score 4):

If you open the `Illuminate\Auth\Notifications\VerifyEmail::class;`

The method that generates the URL already uses expiration time which defaults to 1 hour. Unfortunately there is no option to modify that value.

```
/**
 * Get the verification URL for the given notifiable.
 *
 * @param  mixed  $notifiable
 * @return string
 */
protected function verificationUrl($notifiable)
{
    return URL::temporarySignedRoute(
        'verification.verify', Carbon::now()->addMinutes(60), ['id' => $notifiable->getKey()]
    );
}
```

Comment: Thanks, It was not mentioned on the documentation.